# where to keep common code to be used in controllers and views

Tags: php, cakephp

there are cases when i require to run the same logic both in controller and view, i thought they may have a shared code, for example when to display an edit link and the same logic should check for edit permission in controller , where should i keep such code so that same can be used in controllers as well as views, I am okay to write a a component wrapper and a view wrapper for this method but the core logic should be common.

Some mentioned bootrap is a place but putting there do i have all the cake defined parameters or constants available from that location? or there is a better place

**EDIT**
I gave only authentication related example but there can be more cases like, a view helper for displaying data/time based on offset time set in database (system time + offsetime), i have been forced to use of same code in controllers also (ajax output). What does it imply that in common code we not only have shared logic but also some shared data too, so for only session classes appears to be providing shared data!

Comment: doesn't CakePHP have a Dependency Injection Solution? Like a DI Container to store Services? If not, use the Symfony2 DI Container Component. And do read up on the topic first: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to implement ACL controlled links - there are other ways. I suggest asking about how to do _specifically_ x - instead of broad questions like this.

Comment: @AndreschSerj: That would be awfully bad practice: by the time the view is executed/comes into play, no more logic should be performed, apart for some loops and ifs... services are part of the model layer, which should be accessed from the controller, not the view

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem i didn't want to suggest to use services in the view. The OP asked for a place to store common logic. My bad for not being precise enough. sorry.

Comment: @AndreschSerj: Well, seeing as this question is asking for a way to share logic between controllers and views, and your suggesting DI to store (and thus make available) services, I hope you can see why I got the impression you were suggesting that approach :-p

Comment: @AD7six acl is an overkill for simple applications like, in past i almost implemented acl but later dropped it.

Comment: Its not my suggestion - it's my guess at what the question means. Your edit doesn't really clarify anything.

Comment: @AD7six so, how to do it? any little hint ?

Comment: How to edit the question to be specific instead of vague (last hint)?

Comment: I think i have a closest answers from @EliasVanOotegem that fullfills 100% of my auth related requirements, i added that edit to show another case where i was looking for further suggestion.

Comment: @treemonster19: I fail to see how the edit would make me change anything about my answer: the data is gathered by the Model layer, which is accessed by the controller. The Model layer is where your logic resides, and where the data comes from. The controller passes it on to the view. If it's an AJAX request, then it can simply send back a JSON string, if not: there's a  `TimeHelper`, or a `TextHelper`...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem in auth its nice by only setting true/false view vars, but in later example we set a view var for offset time and create a code for calculating time() + offset time in views (or helper)? i cannot do this processing in advance from controller with 20 records using a loop as there is already a loop in view. I was not aware of TimeHelper for this particular case yes i can use this, but do I have to manually code a TimeComponent in for use in controller?

Comment: @treemonster19: I can't answer that definitively. Without being familiar with the specifics of your project, the best I can do is suggest those things that are considered _best practice_, and offer you documentation on them. Anything else would be a stab in the dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the whole, I'm inclined to say you're not going about this the right way. If you have to include the same piece of logic in both the controller and the view, chances are you're doing the same work twice, which is always a bad idea. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is something you probably heard about a million times before.

However, in the case you mention (authentication): this is done in the Controller, which relies on the Model layer to find out if the user has the permissions to see/use edit links.
Based on the data the controller receives from the Model layer, it should do one of the following things:

- choose to render a specific view (with/without edit links)
- Present the user with an error view
- redirect to the login

For the first case, an editable and non-editable view, you *can* choose to use the same view script, and use [a helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) to pass on the session information to the view. Effectively giving the view the means to check a users' session, check if the user in question has the rights required to see the edit links and render them...

Another simple fix would be to set a property of the view to `true` for editable and `false` for non-editable in the controller, and check that bool flag in the view. No *extra* logic required.

The main thing here is that what you're after is authenticating the user. By the time you reached the view, the route is a given, there's no way back. If you find yourself still having to validate the users' identity, you've made a mistake at an earlier point: the controller, and model layer is where this kind of *core logic* should reside.
A view contains no logic other than its own: a loop or 2, some if-else's... nothing more.

The rule of thumb, then is: the first thing the controller does is *authenticate the user*. The authentication itself is the concern of the Model layer: no actual core/business logic should be in the controller. Based on the findings the model layer returns (authentication failed, or user has rights to do X, but not Y), the controller can redirect, throw errors or choose to render a specific view.
Only after all these things are performed the view is brought in. If there's a user in play, the view can assume that this user is valid, and has the rights required to see its contents. ***The view does not validate data, nor does it authenticate users***.

To authenticate a user the Cake-specific way [there's a core Authentication component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) that seems to be quite well documented. See if you can't use that...

Comment: i understand if this is tried could become a violation of MVC pattern. I have tried session helpers and result is not pretty I again ended up comparing user groups ids, your later suggestion of storing true/false value is workable it seems.

Comment: @treemonster19: If using a session helper is making your view a mess, then also consider creating distinct viewscripts, and let the controller decide which view should be rendered. That way, you may end up with 2 or 3 clean scripts. The downside is that you might have to edit each script if something changes, the upside: the scripts are maintainable enough to do just that

Comment: i think maintaining multiple views somes at big cost, for one part of code re-usability we have duplicate much code in views

Comment: But then you can use one view with embedded elements, where each element has the code for different users

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple functions to bootstrap, but another option would be to create a class in app/Lib/ using static methods. Then from any controller you can include the library and use the methods defined:-

```
App::uses('MyLibrary', 'Lib');
```

If all controllers need to use these just include the library in AppController.

For your views I'd then consider defining a View Helper that would apply the methods used in MyLibrary.

Comment: static methods are not really cool for unit-tests aren't they :-/

Comment: @AD7six I've perhaps misunderstood the original question, but I don't see why my answer is that bad considering this is how Cake works for certain libraries like CakeTime. The question also seemed to imply that the functionaliy they were building could sit in bootstrap and not rely on models.

Comment: IMO it's too early to answer, the question isn't clear. However: `the same logic should check for edit permission` <- implies an authorization check in the controller when accessed (normal), and since it's mentioned to be the same in the view, also an authorization check in/before the view to render the link to access it (a guess. not normal). Btw I haven't voted on your answer.

Comment: /i upvoted this, i guess its not incorrect but its not going to do any magic with the static methods still by combination with Session classes maybe some data can be shared too.